# Why am I not getting the prepackaged error messages from angular in webstorm 8?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

I'm at my wit's end with this.. for some reason my angular errors always show up cryptic like so:

[image]

I can usually figure out the problem but in general I'm looking to see if anyone has any input on how to get the nice error messages that angular supposedly shows that I've never seen before where it has a link to the site with more information as well as more verbose error details.

Any help would be appreciated. Please feel free to leave a comment pointing me in the direction of obtaining more information as I'm not quite sure what to look for with respect to this problem.

It's also worth noting that I get the same "Uncaught Object" message in my dev console for chrome. I'm sorry I don't have more info but if it's worth anything I was expecting an error along the lines of:

[image]

which is referenced by the line number.

Comment: It's a common problem, I think angular has an open issue about this uninformative error message but I'm too lazy to find it. Anyways, you can debug at the throw line (3845 on your screenshot) and see the name of the module it failed to instantiate and the stack trace.

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Angular version 1.2.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your IDE using Chrome as the underlying browser?

Chrome has annoyingly started doing this to long error messages. See this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5568) and in the Angular project, as well as this [blog post](http://www.congral.com/2014/05/29/have-you-already-encountered-the-uncaught-object-exception/) for some details.

So whenever I see "Uncaught Error" in Chrome, I switch to Firefox to see the actual error message.

Another solution is to switch to the bleeding edge version of Chrome, [Chrome Canary](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html), and then make your IDE use that.

Comment: I'll try this but my coworker who uses Chrome as well hasn't noticed any problems.